# How to create a CSS typing animation that spans multiple lines of text?

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to get the typing animation effect to continue one line at a time when the size of parent container forces the text to span multiple lines.

```css
/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: green;
  }
}

.animated-text {
  font: bold 1.45em monospace;
  color: black;
  border-right: 0.6em solid;
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  animation: typing 3.5s steps(40, end), blink-caret 0.9s step-end infinite;
}

.container {
  border: 10px solid;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  height: 32%;
  left: 35%
}
```

```html
  <div class='container'>
        <h1 class='animated-text'>The typing effect should continue line by line at a time when the text needs to wrap</h1>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for the answer to this question as well.

The closest I could find was [this - multiline typewriter effect](https://codepen.io/jenlky/pen/dKoQrW). However, you have to manually set the width of each p tag. I've yet to find a way to dynamically set the width of each line.

All lines except for the last line uses border-right to display the typewriter effect, only the last line has blink animation which is the typewriter cursor.

```
<div class="css-typing">
  <p>
    Hi I'm Jenssen Lee! Looking to start my career as a Front-End Developer in Singapore.
  </p>
  <p>
    I have experience with HTML, SASS, Bootstrap, JavaScript, jQuery, React, Node.js, Express.
  </p>
  <p>
    This site was designed and built by me - the code is available on Github.
  </p>
</div>

.css-typing p {
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.css-typing p:nth-child(1) {
  width: 780px; /* manually set width */
  -webkit-animation: type 2s steps(40, end);
  animation: type 2s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(2) {
  width: 780px; /* manually set width */
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type2 2s steps(40, end);
  animation: type2 2s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(3) {
  width: 620px; /* manually set width */
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type3 5s steps(20, end), blink .5s step-end infinite alternate;
  animation: type3 2s steps(20, end), blink .5s step-end infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    border: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    border: none;
  }
}

@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@keyframes type3 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type3 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  50% {
    border-color: tranparent;
  }
}
```